# How to store value like 1.00 as double in MongoDB using mongoose using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store the value 1.0, 1.1 (as double not string) like this in mongo DB but when using schema type number it stores 1.1 but not 1.0(it's converted into 1). double dataType not supports.
When we update directly from Robo 3T its store 1.0 as double but not via mongoose

Comment: As a number (but also as a double), 1.0 equals 1

Comment: Thanks to comment, its okay 1.0 equals to 1 but I need to store 1.0 like this when we update directly from Robo 3T its store 1.0 as double but not via mongoose

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mongoosejs/double

Comment: Thanks, npmjs.com/package/@mongoosejs/double not compatible with latest(mongoose@6.3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Add `mongoose.Decimal128` in the schema.

```
const vehicleSchema = new Schema({ fuelLevel: mongoose.Decimal128 });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want store value like 
{
 val:1.0
} but when store with Decimal128 the value will store like:
{
  val: NumberDecimal("1.0")
}